How can I use 2 for loops together (one for each year and one for each day)?
I think I calculated correctly the average distance between three consecutive values when the condition (described in the code) is met. However, I did this calculation only for a single year and I don't know how to do it for every year. Could you please help me? I think I need another for loop but when I tried this I failed.
set.seed(123)  
years <- rep(2010:2014, each=365)
months <- rep(rep(1:12, each=31), 5)[1:(5*365)]  
days <- rep(1:31, times=5*12)[1:(5*365)]  

# Create a data frame with year, month, day, 
x <- rnorm(5*365, mean=15, sd=5)
df <- data.frame(Year=years, Month=months, Day=days, Values=x)
library(magrittr)
df_filt <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Year == 2010)

df_filt$Distance <- NA

for (i in 3:nrow(df_filt)) {
  if (df_filt$Values[i] > df_filt$Values[i - 1] && 
      df_filt$Values[i - 1] > df_filt$Values[i - 2]) {
    df_filt$Distance[i] <-
      (1/3)*(sqrt((df_filt$Values[i] - df_filt$Values[i - 2])^2) +
               sqrt((df_filt$Values[i] - df_filt$Values[i - 1])^2) +
               sqrt((df_filt$Values[i - 2] - df_filt$Values[i - 1])^2))
  } else {
    df_filt$Distance[i] <- NA
  }
}

df_filt$Distance2 <- NA

for (i in 3:nrow(df_filt)) {
  if (df_filt$Values[i] > df_filt$Values[i - 1] &&
      df_filt$Values[i - 1] < df_filt$Values[i - 2]) {
    df_filt$Distance[i] <- 
      (1/3)*(sqrt((df_filt$Values[i] - df_filt$Values[i - 2])^2) +
               sqrt((df_filt$Values[i] - df_filt$Values[i - 1])^2) +
               sqrt((df_filt$Values[i - 2] - df_filt$Values[i - 1])^2))
  } else {
    df_filt$Distance[i] <- NA
  }
}

sum <- colSums(df_filt[5:6], na.rm=TRUE)
print(sum)

final_sum <- sum(sum)
print(final_sum)


Welcome to SO.  I suspect you don't need any loops to do this, but it's difficult/impossible to be sure without seeing the output you expect based on your test input.

i edited the code, i want to do the same again for a different condition and then i would like to find the sum of these differences for each condition. I want this to happen for each year. It must be a faster way to do this but i ' m newbie in R!

Yes, as per the comment the loops could be eliminated.  Use the lag function to remove the first group of loops then use the summarize function handle the yearly totals.
Depending on how you would like to handle the first couple days of the year you may need to change the placement of the distance calculations.
library(dplyr)

df_filt <- df

Distance1 <- ifelse( (df_filt$Values > lag(df_filt$Values, 1, 0)) & (lag(df_filt$Values, 1, 0) > lag(df_filt$Values, 2, 0)), 
                (1/3)*(sqrt((df_filt$Values - lag(df_filt$Values, 2))^2) +
                          sqrt((df_filt$Values - lag(df_filt$Values, 1))^2) +
                          sqrt((lag(df_filt$Values, 2) - lag(df_filt$Values, 1))^2)),  NA)

Distance2 <- ifelse( (df_filt$Values > lag(df_filt$Values, 1)) & (lag(df_filt$Values, 1) < lag(df_filt$Values, 2))  , 
                 (1/3)*(sqrt((df_filt$Values - lag(df_filt$Values, 2))^2) +
                           sqrt((df_filt$Values - lag(df_filt$Values, 1))^2) +
                           sqrt((lag(df_filt$Values, 2) - lag(df_filt$Values, 1))^2)) , NA)

df_filt %>% mutate(Distance1, Distance2) %>% 
   group_by(Year) %>% 
   summarize(sumDistance1 = sum(Distance1, na.rm=TRUE), sumDistance2 = sum(Distance2, na.rm=TRUE))

